# How to config trust between two realms in one KDC?

Tags: security, kerberos, hadoop

I'm using one KDC to manage two realms in two different databases (like `krb5kdc -p 2001 -r REALM1 -p 2002 -r REALM2`), how can I config them to trust each other? I know the steps when it's in two different KDCs, (something like `add_principal krbtgt/REALM1@REALM2`). Could they be configed in the same way? Or just no need to config, they have trusted each other already casuing in the same KDC service?

If I have two hadoop clusters whose realms are different, which way is better? One KDC or two KDCs?

Answer (score 0):

The overall steps are the same. However, as each realm *usually* has a separate database, you need to make sure you're adding the principals to the correct database; i.e. you still need to add two copies of the same "trust" principal through both `kadmin.local -r REALM1` and `kadmin.local -r REALM2`.

You do not need to specify custom ports for each realm – 'krb5kdc' can in fact serve multiple realms on the same default port, distinguishing them based on the realm of client principal.

It is only 'kadmind' that is limited to one realm per port, and you'll likely need to run two instances of kadmind, one per realm (hence the suggestion to use `kadmin.local` in this case).